# Issues scrolling to div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, onclick

I am having trouble creating a jQuery function that is called by an HTML onclick event handler that finds the ID of that particular element, adds a "#" to the start of it and "-container" to the end and assigns it to a variable. This variable is then used to scroll the window to that particular div. My HTML is as follows and the jQuery function is below it.

```
<div class="skill-grid">

    <div id="science" onclick="ScrollToDiv()">
        <div class="skill-text">science</div>
    </div>

    <div id="coding" onclick="ScrollToDiv()">
        <div class="skill-text">coding</div>
    </div>

    <div id="photography" onclick="ScrollToDiv()">
        <div class="skill-text">photography</div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="science-container"></div>
<div id="coding-container"></div>
<div id="photography-container"></div>
```

The function in jQuery I have written is as follows:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function ScrollToDiv() {
    var container = "#" + $(this).attr('id') + "-container";
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(container).offset().top }, 2000);
    }    
</script>
```

I do feel like I am missing something very simple. Any help would be much appreciated! I am also open to a new/better way to do this!

My thanks for your time,

Finn

Comment: What is `this`? Not what you expect, I'm guessing. Try attaching the handler with jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update this:

```
onclick="ScrollToDiv(this)" 
// in the above parameter you have to pass the current object's context.
```

pass the current context in your method. and update the function as:

```
function ScrollToDiv(el) { // <---get the current object from the param here
    var container = "#" + $(el).attr('id') + "-container"; 
                    //----^^^^^ wrap it as jQuery object
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(container).offset().top 
    }, 2000);
}
```

---

Try to be unobtrusive as much as possible:

#### As you are using jQuery do this:

put your original function in global scope:

```
function ScrollToDiv() {
    var container = "#" + $(this).attr('id') + "-container";
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(container).offset().top 
    }, 2000);
}
```

and add this script:

```
jQuery(function($){
     $('.skill-grid > div').click(ScrollToDiv);
});
```

---

Or if you can change your ids to class like this:

```
<div class="skill-grid">
    <div id="science">
        <div class="skill-text">science</div>
    </div>
    <div id="coding">
        <div class="skill-text">coding</div>
    </div>
    <div id="photography">
        <div class="skill-text">photography</div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="science"></div>
<div class="coding"></div>
<div class="photography"></div>
```

then you can do this:

```
function ScrollToDiv() {
    var container = "." + this.id;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(container).offset().top 
    }, 2000);
} 

jQuery(function($){
     $('.skill-grid > div').click(ScrollToDiv);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly it. I need to do some reading up on how to use 'this' it seems. Cheers!

Comment: It would've been nice if you explained how it works, rather than just give him the answer.

Comment: But +1 for the nice and swift response!

Answer (score 0):

re-think your html struct if you can:

```
        <div class="skill-grid">
            <div id="science">
                <div class="skill-text"><a class="click" href="#science-container">science</a></div>
            </div>

            <div id="coding">
                <div class="skill-text"><a class="click" href="#coding-container">coding</a></div>
            </div>

            <div id="photography">
                <div class="skill-text"><a class="click" href="#photography-container">photography</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="science-container"></div>
        <div id="coding-container"></div>
        <div id="photography-container"></div>


        <script>
            $(function(){
                $('a.click').on('click', function(e){
                    var offset = $(this.hash).offset().top;
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: offset
                    }, 2000
                );
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```